# ROS Build farm help

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m trying to be as exhaustive as possible. I have no previous experience in setting up a ros buildfarm before and I have very little knowledge about it. I tried to follow the documentation here (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment). I got to the second step after mirroring this (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config) repository and tried to change the parameters inside the common.yaml file. I changed the master ip, repo ip, jenkins uname and password. But the other things listed in the documentation is not available in the common.yaml file.

I’m making my machine as the master and a raspberry pi as the repo and another raspberry pi as agent. The master IP is my machine’s IP and the repo and the agent IPs are the two raspi’s IP. In common.yaml file, I edited these stuffs and changed the jenkins::slave::ui_user and ui_pass to my github username and password which is authorized in my jenkins account. Then, autoreconfigure is setup to be false in the common.yaml file but it is listed as branch in the documentation. Should I go about changing this ?

Coming to ssh keys, the key specified is the public key I generated using the ssh keygen command in my master machine ?

Anybody who has setup a buildfarm before, it will be great if you could provide me with an example and if possible explain why we are performing each step along the way.

P.S: This is not my homework. This is something I’m really willing to learn. Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289032/ros-build-farm-help/) by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2018-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, welcome to the community of buildfarmers! You've come to the right place with your question, but if you notice errors or have suggestions for improvement, you're invited to open issues or pull requests directly on https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment or https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config. Use the first one if you're not sure where an issue belongs and we'll help guide you to the right place. Your questions help improve the project!

> raspberry pi as the repo and another raspberry pi as agent.

Just for background info: the ROS buildfarm doesn't currently support cross-compilation, arm compilation happens inside docker containers with arm-native filesystems that bundle the qemu-user-{arm,aarch64} interpreters so they can be run on AMD64 hosts. I have started playing with native ARM64 support for https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment but it is far from complete or stable. I would be very pleasantly surprised if puppet runs without errors on a Raspberry Pi.

Are you planning to build packages exclusively for Raspberry Pi or are you also hoping to build x86 packages? I think you'll need at least one AMD64 agent to build x86 and x86_64 packages. With qemu you can also use these to build ARM packages.

As for running your repo host on a Raspberry Pi, I can't think of any reason off the top of my head why that won't work, but it hasn't been tested as far as I'm aware.

What operating system are you running on your Pis? Ubuntu Xenial, Raspbian, or something else?

---

Now let me try to address your individual questions.

> I edited these stuffs and changed the jenkins::slave::ui_user and ui_pass to my github username and password which is authorized in my jenkins account.

One thing to watch out for is that the puppet configuration will override your Jenkins auth settings with the following authentication strategy and security realm https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment/blob/2a3d6b409c0e85336ecbcd6e7a3663f913872e27/modules/jenkins_files/files/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml#L8-L12. Running puppet may render you unable to sign in with your GitHub credentials. It's not something that's been tested much. The buildfarm_deployment is designed to be in full control of its jenkins master. If you have other projects using the same Jenkins master you might need to avoid using puppet and try to use it as a guide for setting Jenkins up manually.

The Jenkins agent credentials (referred to as `jenkins::slave::ui_user` and `jenkins::slave::ui_pass` in hiera are intended to match the admin username and password hash set in the master.yaml config: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config/blob/3e1dd83cba87099dc925decfe2e26222f52c8dc1/hiera/hieradata/buildfarm_role/master.yaml#L1-L2

You can use a utility like https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/jenkins_bcrypt_pw_util to generate a Jenkins password hash suitable for that line in your config.

> Coming to ssh keys, the key specified is the public key I generated using the ssh keygen command in my master machine ?

This is the ssh key that will be used by your jenkins agents to publish packages, documentation, and generated status page html to your repo host. The config used to have an intact keypair but this seemed to me too egregious of a security risk so I replaced the matching keypair with a public key and a suggestion to supply your own key pair. Since the instructions for doing so are not clear I've opened a pull request with additional info here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config/pull/32 Let me know if the improved comments help and from there I'll enhance the README documentation.

You'll also want to provide a current ssh host key for your repo host to allow your agents to connect to it without manual intervention. This is another step that could do with improved instructions. I use the ed25519 keys when I can because they're short and easy to copy. I've opened an additional PR to improve those instructions (and fix a bug in the default config) https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config/pull/33

> Then, autoreconfigure is setup to be false in the common.yaml file but it is listed as branch in the documentation. Should I go about changing this ?

For small buildfarm setups, I actually advocate keeping the autoreconfigure script disabled entirely. Hiera configurations are hierarchical so setting it to [false in common.yaml](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config/blob/3e1dd83cba87099dc925decfe2e26222f52c8dc1/hiera/hieradata/common.yaml#L29) can allow it to be overridden in agent.yaml or repo.yaml which are [higher in priority in the hiera configuration](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config/blob/3e1dd83cba87099dc925decfe2e26222f52c8dc1/hiera/hiera.yaml). autoreconfigure on master [can cause problems](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment/issues/160) and so is not currently advised.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-04-18**:
Firstly, Thank you for taking your time in answering my questions. I still have some fundamental questions about learning how to setup build farm. I'm a total noob and I understood bits and pieces of your answer. But I'm still lacking the overall picture on how to setup a build farm.

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-04-18**:
The question I'm about to ask could be dumb. Let me tell you the scenario on what exactly I'm trying to achieve. I have a git repo that has a ros package which I developed. I want to setup a buildfarm, deploy it and perform continuous integration on it. So how should I go about setting up one ?

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-18**:
No worries. Leave me a comment as to which parts are confusing and I can elaborate. In general we encourage one question per "Question" on answers.ros.org so I may respond with a request to create a new question from a particular comment or edit. It isn't a criticism, just housekeeping.

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-04-18**:
I understand that the github repo instructions are good enough, since I lack basic knowledge of CIs, jenkins I have no idea how to implement one. So it will be great if you could tell me how can I better learn this. Is there any material like [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89yWXXIOisk)

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-18**:\

> I have a git repo that has a ros package which I developed. I want to setup a buildfarm, deploy it and perform continuous integration on it. So how should I go about setting up one ?

This is actually a great candidate (in my opinion) for being asked as a separate question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
I sympathise, as I went through the same struggle. My luck was probably that I may have a bit more experience with build systems and the previous version of the buildfarm. The documentation was not (completely) updated when the Xenial migration was merged.

Getting some familiarity with Jenkins, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
.. CI, cmake, docker and how to run commands on remote machines through SSH might help. That is a lot of knowledge, but you don't need to be a wizard in any of that. That's why the `ros_buildfarm` pkgs exist.

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-04-23**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/289455/how-to-setup-a-buildfarm-for-my-git-repo/ - I have posted a separate question here. Might have similar content. Tried to be specific with my question. Hope you could help. Thanks

**Comment by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) on 2019-08-19**:
@nuclearsandwich Can you please comment on the performance of Docker + QEMU approach.

We configured it and we see a lot of benefits in this approach. However, we have been experiencing a huge compilation time slowdown. A simple talker example takes as much as 60s to compile in armv7 Docker container versus 6s in native Docker container.

Is there any way to speed it up?

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2019-08-19**:
The performance is not good. Looking at a random package (rtabmap_ros on Melodic) it looks like a build takes around 45 min for amd64 and anywhere from 2-5 hours for armhf or armv8 via QEMU.

There's no panacea here. We're sticking with native compilation on the ROS 2 build farm but have been using native ARM servers from Packet.net and AWS. Maintaining a buildfarm of development boards isn't an option for us but it might be an option depending on your needs. As mentioned the buildfarm_deployment is not meant to be used on ARM and so takes a bit of tweaking after puppet runs.